# sql query help (very specific)

Tags: sql

I have looked all over the internet for an answer to my question to why my sql statement returns false.  I checked it out on the sql validator over at mimer and all I got was that I used the reserved word name.  There should be something in my database that matches this so here it is:

Here is how I create the sql statement:

```
$title = 'SELECT * FROM item, categories WHERE item.title 
LIKE "%'.implode('%" OR item.title LIKE "%', $data).'%"'.' 
AND categories.name = '.$category;
```

And this is the result:

```
SELECT * FROM item, categories WHERE item.title LIKE "%hello%" 
OR item.title LIKE "%world%" OR item.title 
LIKE "%Joomla%" OR item.title LIKE "%Animal%" AND categories.name = Book
```

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. "item"."title". Single quotes are for string literals, e.g. '%hello%'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably think about your (lack of) parentheses.  I'm not sure specifically what you are trying to accomplish,

but this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM item, categories
WHERE item.title LIKE "%hello%"
OR item.title LIKE "%world%"
OR item.title LIKE "%Joomla%"
OR item.title LIKE "%Animal%"
AND categories.name = "Book"
```

is vastly different from this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM item, categories
WHERE (
    item.title LIKE "%hello%"
    OR item.title LIKE "%world%"
    OR item.title LIKE "%Joomla%"
    OR item.title LIKE "%Animal%"
)
AND categories.name = "Book"
```

Also, like the others say, Book should be in quotes (like I have done here).

```
AND categories.name = "Book"
```

Comment: Excellent point. Also, you may want it to be: 

categories.name = 'Book'

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the word `Book` with quotes.

I'm betting you also need parentheses.

```
SELECT * FROM item, categories WHERE (item.title LIKE "%hello%" 
OR item.title LIKE "%world%" OR item.title 
LIKE "%Joomla%" OR item.title LIKE "%Animal%") AND categories.name = "Book"
```

Answer (score 0):

the last part, categories.name, is that a string? if so it should be

```
and categories.name = 'book'
```

note the quotes around book

Comment: also, use @gabriel's answer as you'll need parenthesis around the OR's